# Timing in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My canvas is acting as a map. The user gets to click on the canvas and it plots a marker on the map(canvas). The co-ordinates are stored in an array.

When the user clicks a play button the canvas plots the first array marker in its position, a second later plots the second marker, another second later plots the third marker and so on.

How could I achieve this? I've tried using a for loop and calling a setTimeout function that passes the value of i in the loop but loops go to fast and I can't get my head around it.

```
 function timer() {
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        play(i);
    }
}


   function play(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(array[i].x, array[i].y);
    ctx.lineTo(array[i].x,array[i].y);
    cursor(array[i].x,array[i].y);
   }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set interval and clear the interval when the counter (that is incremented within this) reaches a certain point. For example: -

```
var t;
var counter = 0;
var array = ['your', 'data'];

function timer() {
    t = setInterval(play, 1000);
}

function play() {
    if (counter !== array.length) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(array[counter].x, array[counter].y);
        ctx.lineTo(array[counter].x,array[counter].y);
        cursor(array[counter].x,array[counter].y);
        counter++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(t);
        t = null;  
    }
}

timer(); // begin calling play() every 1 second for array.length (2 in example) loops
```

Comment: This is good except the 99 as maxCount. Just pull in the array length. :)

Comment: setInterval is not a good way to do it, as it will tick even if previous ticks have not completed. setTimeout would be better, or preferably requestAnimationFrame, but with logic to handle whether the frame should be processed or not. And if you use requestAnimationFrame, then ticking will cease, if you move to a different tab, effectively placing your animation on pause, ready for you when you return to the tab. Much more efficient with the browser's clock cycles too.

Answer (score 2):

Use requestAnimationFrame and store the difference in tick values, so that you only process your change after each second has elapsed.

If you can't use requestAnimationFrame, then use setTimeout(play, 1000) to call the play function again after 1000 seconds. And simply increment your index at the end and stop before you get an index out of bounds, of course.

**Do NOT use setInterval**, as that can overrun your previous interval's operations. It does not wait for completion of the previous piece of processing to complete.

E.g.

```
<script>
    var lastTick = 0;
    var elapsed = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var array = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    function animationLoop(tick) {
        var diff = tick - lastTick;
        elapsed += diff;
        if (elapsed > 1000) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(array[index].x, array[index].y);
            ctx.lineTo(array[index].x, array[index].y);
            cursor(array[index].x, array[index].y);
            elapsed -= 1000;
            index++;
        }

        if (index < array.length) {
            lastTick = tick;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
        }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout may not be the best solution. You would be better of using setInterval to call a separate function every x milliseconds. Can you paste the for loop in question?

**edit**:

First of all I see that you are using canvas, so I am guessing googlemaps api? Even so you should be using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for any animation intensive work. Also since the work is being done in your play function the timer function is practically irrelevant.

I am a little rusty on requestAnimationFrame myself, but I think that this code might help a bit. I think that the setInterval portion would make the requestAnimationFrame pointless, and you need to move the actual timing into the play function. I just can't remember how to do it.

```js
    var i = 0;
    
    /*
    * change the 1000 to make the animation faster or slower.
    * 1000ms == 1s so 10000 = 10 seconds
    */
    setInterval(timer(), 1000);

    function timer() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(play);
    }

    function play() {
      if (i <= array.length) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(array[i].x, array[i].y);
        ctx.lineTo(array[i].x, array[i].y);
        cursor(array[i].x, array[i].y);
        i++;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(play);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, `requestAnimationFrame` is the way to go -- its more efficiently integrated with hardware refresh cycles, etc.  Also, the latest version of rAF automatically sends in a timestamp argument that you can use to throttle the loop to your desired pace. Upvote.

Comment: That's awesome, how can you access that timestamp? Does it get attached to the function you call it on, or is it saved as a variable of window? edit: btw thanks for my first upvote! :)

Comment: The timestamp is sent in as the only argument. You can label it anything your desire in your function definition. `function play(currentTime){ console.log(currentTime); }`

Comment: I see, I noticed @ManoDestra had the animationLoop with the tick argument. This is the same thing right?

Comment: Yes, it's the automatic timestamp -- they called it `tick`, but you can name it anything you wish.